# How to turn a short voltage pulse into a long voltage pulse or increase bandpass

Tags: signal, signal-processing, pulse

First I am not an electrical engineer, but I am on a mission, so please forgive my lack of resources and ability to explain my concepts.

I am designing a device for people with blindness. Currently it just blinks faster when objects are nearer, but I want to have it output a tone/frequency dependent on distance. To do that, I have to convert these short pulses into long pulses. The voltage of the long pulses must be dependent on the voltage of the short pulses. How short are the pulses? Well the speed of light short, only a few nanoseconds in duration, but still enough to light up an LED or output a beep to a speaker. Currently I am using the short pulse to charge a capacitor that triggers the next range finding sequence. When objects are near it the sequence occurs quickly and you hear many beeps, when objects are far away the beeps slow to 1hz. This method is not good for battery duration. Instead I want the range finding sequence to only sample the distance once every second and then output a specific tone based on this distance. The tones would be tuned to a persons ability to hear and thus allow them to learn to distinguish exact distances.

The first thing I tried was applying a lowpass filter, but even if I got this working correctly this just causes the tone to taper off really quickly. Hence the tone is not consistent. Here are my signals with a lowpass filter applied. The first signal is distance measuring at ~1ft (30cm), and the second is at ~7ft (2m). The maximum range will be up to 40m in the daylight.

[image]

Here is a photo of an ideal signal conversion. The short pulses converted into a long consistent voltage that I can transform into tones based on differing voltages. The bandpass of the signal doesn't have to be precise but long enough in duration for someone to hear the the unique tone. 500ms to 900ms would likely be perfect.
[image]

Comment: Would you prefer to do it in an MCU (programming skills required but easy to tweak) or discrete?

Comment: If the pulse duration is proportional to distance, integrate the pulse and sample at end of the pulse. Then you can use this voltage to generate a tone proportional to distance or whatever you need.

Comment: Use a monostable.

Comment: Are you using this kind of sensor ? https://www.st.com/en/imaging-and-photonics-solutions/time-of-flight-sensors.html

Comment: @Andyaka So with a monostable I can define the output duration, will the output voltage change depending on input voltage? If so, I would then use this to drive another oscillator to get the needed tone? Or could it be accomplished with a single oscillator?

Comment: @Antonio51 no, they don't provide enough range. I use an Infrared Diode up to 100ma modulated at 38khz.

Comment: You asked this: `How to turn a short voltage pulse into a long voltage pulse`. You didn't ask anything else and I'm not about to be swept along a path of evolving requirements. May I suggest you fully define what you think you need and post your schematic.

Comment: @winny I actually know how to accomplish it with analog input and programming an attiny85 .etc. I am trying to learn how to do it without a microcontroller so I can fully understand everything. It also saves battery life.

Comment: Ok. You specified only 7 feet ~2.3 m. This kind (also multizones, multi targets) provides a range of 3m ~ 10 feet. Ok for your choice. Could you specify the duration of pulses (min-max) ? Anyway (quasi), Attiny85 would be more flexible.

Comment: @Antonio51 2.3m is just the distance to my ceiling from my table. The range of the device is much farther, my goal is 40m in daylight.

Comment: @Andyaka I just built a monostable with a 555. The output voltage was not dependent on the input voltage. This got me halfway there. However, I need the output voltage to change when the input voltage changes.

Comment: Recap:  You have a sensor signal that varies in amplitude as a function of distance.  The shorter the pulse, the shorter the distance.  You want to produce a tone burst of constant duration (500-900 ms) and constant loudness, with a frequency that varies as a function of the input pulse amplitude; as the input pulse gets shorter, the frequency increases.  Yes / No - ?  If this is correct, you want a gated, voltage-controlled oscillator driving a speaker.

Comment: @analogkid
That is Exactly what I am doing! Now to research. Do you have a suggestion on where to start my research? As I don't know much about the gated aspect of the vco.

Comment: @Tech-Com as I said earlier: `May I suggest you fully define what you think you need and post your schematic`

Comment: Doing this fully in the analog domain certainly has a beauty to it but from the practical and especially v2.0 development perspective I'd definitely drop a microcontroller in there. You can also apply correction curves, calibration etc very easily with one.

Comment: @AnalogKid sorry to bother you, would you be able to elaborate a bit more? After a day of research I've not determined the logic gate required to trigger the vco. The vco I have made requires a constant voltage source. Again I am left with the original issue that the pulse is too short to drive it long enough to produce the needed tone. Do you have a recommendation for terminology I should search? Thanks

Comment: Do you have any feel for the type of waveform you want to drive the speaker.  A sine wave sounds nice, but is a more complex VCO.  A square wave sounds brittle, but is more simple to start with.

Comment: @AnalogKid no experiments yet on the preferred waveform. I'd prefer it be more pleasant, but at the moment I've only considered practicality.

Answer (score 1):

Proposition (first draft) for a sampler ToF (to be adapted ... only idea).

Input pulses are short. Switched current source to be updated ...

[image]

Inverted input pulse ... Added also resistor at the output to see decay effect.

Update : [with this](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PSSI2021SAY.pdf) . Op-amp AD8601, "slow".

[image].

The sampling function can be done, as fast as possible after the pulse (rising or falling edge triggered), by ATTiny85 ADC.

The reset of the capacitor may be done also by ATTiny85 (FET switch ?), before "asking" ToF function.

Attiny85 may complete the tone generation with voltage measured just after the end sampling phase. Using also low power capabilities for long time battery. Then go "sleeping", if necessary.

You could use also, as suggested, a VCO as NE566 but lower voltage.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough explanation. Do you think there is an IC that has a similar function? I will build this and start testing.